# Using ECDiffieHellmanCng to exchange keys

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, ecdhe

We plan to use ECDHE algorithm to exchange keys between client and server so that both can derive a common secret key to encrypt messages

Based on what I have read, to use ECDHE algorithm both parties (client and server) should agree on a pair of "common" values (p, g) first. Then each party will  use a private key to generate a shared key ie client uses a private key (P1) to generate a shared key (S1) and server uses a private key (P2) to generate a shared key (S2)
Ref: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange#Description]

Common value here refers to the common paint. These are actually the mod value (p) and base value (g) used by both parties to generate the shared keys.

Both parties then exchange the shared keys (S1 and S2) and use it with their own private key (P1 or P2) to derive the common secret (K)

When I look at samples that use ECDiffieHellmanCng to generate keys, I do not see an option to specify these "common" values anywhere. In our case, I was expecting both client and server to agree on p and g and then use those values with "ECDiffieHellmanCng" to generate the common shared key.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellmancng?view=netframework-4.7.2

I see Alice and Bob create new instance of ECDiffieHellmanCng - do they both internally use the same common values (p and g)?

Comment: p and g are for IFC Diffie-Hellman, not ECC Diffie-Hellman. .NET doesn’t have public API for classic/IFC DH. For ECDH you pick a curve in common, which is taken care of via ECDiffieHellman.Create(ECCurve) (or setting KeySize for NIST P-256/384/521)

Comment: Thanks @bartonjs. Can you explain more on setting KeySize to have the common values? As per documentation, specifying key size (256/384/521) creates a random key pair using the keysize. Is it sufficient to use the same keysize at both the client and server side to generate random key pairs? If we exchange these public keys and then both parties derive the secret key using other's public key - will they be the same?

Comment: Yup. Those are the only three allowed numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your question you link to an article explaining (classic/IFC) Diffie-Hellman, which is `secret = (g ^^ (alice * bob)) % p`.  You then mention ECDHE and ask about the ECDiffieHellman(Cng) class in .NET, which is about Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman... the ECC variant of the IFC (Integer Factorization Cryptography) algorithm.

(IFC)DH definitely has a bootstrapping problem of picking a good `(g, p)` combination, and not being tricked by a man in the middle.  For TLS the server side of the connection gets to make up whatever `(g, p)` it wants and then tells the client what it picked, but the client can't really tell if it's being tricked.  If you own both sides you can solve this problem by generating a quality group in the 2048-bit space, and sticking with it.

There is no support for (IFC) Diffie-Hellman provided in-box in .NET.

ECDH has a different set of parameters, which are collectively called "the curve".  For a prime curve (the most common form) the parameters are the tuple `(p, a, b, G, n, h)` (though really `n` and `h` are computations from `(p, a, b, G)`), and then [ECC math is defined on top of that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_cryptography).  Once ECC math is defined, ECDH is `secret = X-Coordinate((alice * bob) * G)`.  ECC has the same pitfalls as (IFC)DH, choosing bad values for the parameters can let tricks be played on the other party. Because of the potential trickery, and the fact that the domain parameters are large, choices of domain parameters get standardized into "named curves".  Two keys on the same curve, by definition, have the same set of domain parameters.  In TLS you are only allowed to use the name (well, the Object Identifier value) of the curve. The server pretty much gets to choose what set of parameters, but for maximum interoperability usually only three curves are chosen from (as of 2018): `secp256r1` (aka NIST P-256), `secp384r1` (aka NIST P-384), and `secp521r1` (aka NIST P-521).

ECDiffieHellmanCng defaults to using `secp521r1`, but you can control the curve in one of three different ways:

### Setting ecdh.KeySize

Changing the KeySize value (setting it to any value other than what it currently holds) results in generating a key onto a curve of that size.  This made total sense for Windows 7, 8, and 8.1... because Windows CNG only supported `secp256r1`, `secp384r1`, and `secp521r1`.  So you can set KeySize to any of { 256, 384, 521 }.

```
using (ECDiffieHellman ecdh = ECDiffieHellman.Create())
{
    ecdh.KeySize = 384;
    ...
}
```

### Creating it that way

Windows 10 added support for more curves, and the sizes became ambiguous.  Does 256 mean `secp256r1` or `brainpoolp256r1` (or `brainpoolp256t1`, `numsp256t1`, `secp256k1`, ...)?  Okay, it means `secp256r1`, and more complicated API exists.

The `ECDiffieHellman.Create` factory has an overload (.NET Core 2.1+, .NET Framework 4.7+) which accepts an `ECCurve`.  So another way to create a curve over `secp384r1` would be

```
using (ECDiffieHellman ecdh = ECDiffieHellman.Create(ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP384))
{
    ...
}
```

## It can still be set later

Maybe you're using DI and can't use the factory nicely.  Well, you can use the `GenerateKey` method (.NET Core 2.1+, .NET Framework 4.7+) to achieve the same results

```
using (ECDiffieHellman ecdh = ECDiffieHellman.Create())
{
    ecdh.GenerateKey(ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP384);
    ...
}
```

---

There are other ways of getting ECCurve values, such as `ECCurve.CreateFromValue("1.3.132.0.34")` or just manually building it from `(p, a, b, G = (Gx, Gy), n, h)`.

Answer (score 0):

- GF(q) denote the finite field with q elements
- p is a base point

Yes, they must use same basepoint and same Elliptic Curve E over a Field Fq. these are public.

Comment: Thanks @kelalaka. My question is - where do we configure these values in the code? All we do here is create new instance of ECDiffieHellmanCng at client side and at server side. What ensures that both use the same p and g values?

Comment: You are distributing the code, right? so put these values both server and client. Everybody must agree on the parameters to have a key exchange.